# Migration from 0.9 socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Socket.io documentation:

> Starting the server
>
> **Previously:**
>
> var io = require('socket.io'); var socket = io.listen(80, { /* options
>   */ });
>
> **Now:**
>
> var io = require('socket.io'); var socket = io({ /* options */ });

Then how can I select server port now ?

Also is it possible to use socket.io without http server (express, node http server and etc.) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it without Express/http, just pass a port to the arguments.

```
var port = 3000;
var io = require('socket.io')(port);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```